# Hermitian and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we prove that if $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ Hermitian and invertible matrix, then for some invertible matrix $J$: $J^*AJ=A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest choice is probably to take $J=A^{-1}$.